# PHP not able to echo form input while using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, input

My PHP file echo's the statement but cannot echo the actual value given by user.

I am using ajax and on the left hand side there is a form which asks for email id.
When the email id is entered and form submitted, the results need to show on the right hand side.

On submitting the form though, the php is able to echo the statement "You have entered :"
but cannot echo the actual email id entered.

Pls help

**This is the form:-**

```
<form action="javascript:ajaxpage('files/search2.php', 'columnTwo')" method="POST">
                        Email :<input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">`
</form>
```

**This is the PHP file:-**

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo "The Email ID is :";
echo $email;
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Only the message "The Email ID is :" is displayed

$email not displayed

Comment: What? I'm not even sure I understand what your problem is, show the code you have already and consider elaborating on your question a bit.

Comment: Some code would be useful, this is a problem with 1000 potential causes and ^2 solutions..

Comment: Do you understand Ajax? And what it is for? That you can't phrase your questions well, tells me that you actually didn't get it. (no offense)
Sust in case you didn't understand it right, here is the w3schools tutorial, the best I could find so far: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp
And if I am right please post your code and describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish. thx.

Comment: Ya do not understand it that well. New to it - Just know that it can be used to display results on the same page. That's exactly what I am trying to do over here. Thanks for the link, I;ll go through it

Answer (score 0):

First : use eventHandlers, not `action="javascript:blah()";`
Second : in your javascript ajax function get the values form your inputs and send them to the php file using post method.You can make your own ajax, but there are also libraries for that, like prototype.js or jquery that are easy to use. Read into it a little, it's quite easy, and return here if you have problems implementing it.